# Flutter: Open a pdf from notification

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

I'm generating a pdf, after that saving it also, in Download directory of our mobile. And while the pdf is getting downloaded, I'm showing the progress using [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications). After pdf is downloaded, I want to open that downloaded pdf as soon as I click the notification, but nothing works. I tried [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file/versions), but it is not compatible with awesome_notifications, what should I do, is there any way that how we download a file and open that from notification, we can do in Flutter?